# prettyPhoto not working on document ready

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I have seen this asked and followed everything but it simply doesnt work for me

Could anyone tell me if they see anything wrong here?
Im not very good at this yet, I am sure it must be something simple.

My goal is to display a popUp once the page is loaded.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){               
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

            function showPopUp() {
                var where = "images/popup.jpg";
                var title = "";
                var comment = "";           

                $.prettyPhoto.open(where, title, comment);
            }

            showPopUp();

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the error (if any) that there is in the console?

Comment: Hmm good question, let me figure out how to check that, excuse me I am new to this.

Comment: and there you go. you just solved it -- yay

Comment: Yep just did thanks for pushing to me use this console. As soon as I saw this error it gave me another search to run on google and I immediately found the solution.

Comment: You should really post your solution as an answer and then accept your own answer.  You'll gain some rep points plus this is for the benefit of others.

Comment: As Sparky672 rightly points out, please can you add an answer explaining your solution.

Comment: Thanks, I did so just now. Was new to the site at time of question and did not understand the workings of the Q/A system much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been fixed in version 3.0.3.

Solution was found here: [isSet is not defined](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/1325/.prettyphoto.open-...-_buildoverlayevent.target-problem-solved/p1)